# Dividing an one-line HTML file to well-formed HTML file

Tags: java, html, parsing

I have an HTML file in which all tags are in one line. I would like to separate each tag and put it on its own line. The end goal is to have a well-formed HTML file.

e.g.

`<html><head><title>StackOverflow</title></head><body></body></html>`

would be converted into:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        StackOverflow
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there an existing Java library that handles this already?

Comment: jsoup should do the job fine.

Comment: macromedia dreamweaver is good for this

Comment: if you want to format your code? copy it into eclipse or any ide. and use their code formater.

Comment: but I have more than 10000 files, so I think it is impossible to do manually

Comment: Note that pretty-printing like this *can* change how it displays. Specifically if whitespace is injected where there was none before.

Comment: Why is Java listed as a requirement for this task?

Comment: Perhaps he wants to do it in java? @TrevorSenior

Comment: It just seemed like a one off thing that a scripting language could handle is all. I wanted to know if the @Hadi was open to other options before writing out an answer - Java it is.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with well-formed HTML files. Even if html tags are on the same line, doesn't mean that the html is not well formed.
What you actually neeed is just a formatter, which basically will make your html more human-readable.
You could take a look at [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/), which can optionally do also a syntax checking.

Comment: I really want each tag in separate line, that is it!!